# Chrome - predictive - URLs on Top

Tags: google-chrome

I've fixed this before and, I don't know what happened, but Chrome is doing it again.
Here is a screenshot.

I'm attempting to search for `dev-n`. It seems the predictive behavior has reverted. I want to see my frequently visited URL - which includes the string `dev-n`. BUT, I see completely unwanted and unrelated results first!? There's an author, a city, some other stuff... and all I want is for the 8th item here - a NodeRED project URL I visit several times a week, to be 1st! I know this is possible. Why this is the default... is beyond me. It's a UX nightmare.

[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue however on my Android built-in browser on my Galaxy phone. The addressbar doesn't suggest URLs anymore, only search results basically turning my browser into a search engine... Very frustrating.